# UIButton touch event being captured by UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` that has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in it, so I can drag it everywhere.

I also have a `UIButton` inside that `UIView` but the touch event in the button for the `.touchUpInside` doesn't fire because it is being captured by the `panGesture`.

If I print the `panGesture.state` whenever I touch the button the `.began` state fires and not the button selector handler.

How can I have the `gestureRecognizer` not capturing the button's touch event?

```
@objc private func panned(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began: print("began")
        // ...
    }
}
```